# Banner Image not Responsive on Mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, html, responsive-images

[Original look of the website on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4JvI.png)

Now, when I apply a css code;

div.masthead-banner.data-bg {

```
background-size: contain !important;
```

}

I get this, On the mobile site the full banner appears with a lot of grey space above and below it:

[After css fix is applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT9XL.png)

However, I would've wanted the image to completely fill the div, is there a way I can achieve this? Thank you.

Website is http://naturessecrets.club

Comment: please provide the url, so we can check it.

Comment: http://naturessecrets.club. Thanks

Comment: @Selasie use `background-size:cover`. Would be helpful

Comment: Tried that, but wouldn’t scale up-to fit the mobile screen size.

Comment: Then you might need another image size of 750 x 1334 and make its  `background-size:cover`. The above resolution is a retina screen i.e it would be around 375 x 667.

Comment: @AnmolSandal Please come clearer. If I understood your reply; I’d need another image of size of 375x667? How do I set that for mobile devices of that screen size only?

Comment: No it would be 750x1334. and you can set it below for media query @media(max-width:767px) {} .it would work for all. i will post a small example shortly

Comment: @Selasie just try this dummy image and make its `background-size:cover` . `https://dummyimage.com/750x1334/#fcbef/0011ff`

Comment: I just inspected in the url you provided and replaced this url with your current url. Working fine.

Comment: sorry @AnmolSandal, doesn't work.

Comment: @PPL it's naturessecrets.club. Thanks.

Comment: @anmol he is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to reduce height of banner and make `background-size: cover` on it.

```
.site-title a {
  font-size: 40px;
} 
div.masthead-banner.data-bg {
    background-size: cover !important;
}
```

[Here is it](http://prntscr.com/jjf62j)

Comment: EVEN BETTER! WOW.

Comment: Yea it will stretch proportionally. Image quality will stay better.

Happy coding

Comment: Sure, sth.kumar2010@gmail.com

Comment: please answer too, if it was helpful

Comment: This was very helpful. This was the best fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background-size to 100% but this will stretch your photo.

I would use different sizes for different devices. Just like this:

```
body {
background-image: url('img_test.jpg'); }

@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
body { 
    background-image: url('img_test.jpg');}}
```

Comment: So in my case; div.masthead-banner.data-bg {
  {
background-image: url('img_test.jpg'); }

@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
div.masthead-banner.data-bg {
  { 
    background-image: url('img_test.jpg');}}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css

[image]

```js
@media only screen and (min-width: 479px) {
    div.masthead-banner.data-bg {
        background-size: cover;
        height: 240px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```